# Expect-webdriverio doesn't work with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

`expect` command from expect-webdriverio is not recognized by TypeScript.
It gives an error

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
```

Here is my `package.json`:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^7.1.0",
    "@percy/cli": "^1.0.0-beta.48",
    "@percy/webdriverio": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.16",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.41",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.0",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.13.8",
    "app-root-path": "^3.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "webdriverio": "^7.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.4.2",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.4.6",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.4.6",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.4.6",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.4.2",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.4.3",
    "@wdio/sync": "^7.4.6",
    "@wdio/types": "^7.4.2",
    "expect": "^26.6.2",
    "expect-webdriverio": "^2.0.2"
  }
```

And this is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./.tsbuild/",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "src/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
      "test/*": [
        "src/step_definitions/*"
      ]
    },
    "target": "es2019",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": false,                   /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
     "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
     "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "types": [
      "webdriverio/sync",
      "node",
      "@wdio/cucumber-framework",
      "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service"
    ], 
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, "esModuleInterop": true are needed for percy 2 to work
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/expect-webdriverio/types/jest-global.d.ts" // added as suggested by IntelliJ IDEA, but seems fishy
  ]
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA is suggesting to add:

```
"node_modules/expect-webdriverio/types/jest-global.d.ts"
```

this line in `tsconfig.json`.
It seems strange to me to have to add file from `node_modules` folder into the `tsconfig.json` file.
What am I doing wrong here?
This is not mentioned anywhere in the official documentation nor I could find boilerplate projects having it set up like that.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found it while taking a closer look to boilerplate projects.

```
"types": [
  "webdriverio/sync",
  "node",
  "@wdio/cucumber-framework",
  "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service",
  "expect-webdriverio" // THIS line needed to be added
],
```

And I removed from `package.json` these lines since the `expect-webdriverio` should be bundled in with higher version of the framework (in this case version 7)

```
 "expect": "^26.6.2",
 "expect-webdriverio": "^2.0.2"
```